# SQL multiple while loop

Tags: sql, while-loop

I'm trying to insert row for each of two variables:

```
DECLARE @nadobaTyp INT = 0;
DECLARE @komodita INT = 0;
DECLARE @nadobaTypMax INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CzEkokomNadobaTyp);
DECLARE @komoditaMax INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CzEkokomNadobaKomodita);

WHILE @nadobaTyp < @nadobaTypMax
BEGIN
    SET @nadobaTyp = @nadobaTyp + 1;
    print 'nadoba typ: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @nadobaTyp);
    WHILE @komodita < @komoditaMax
    BEGIN
        SET @komodita = @komodita + 1;
        print 'komodita: ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @komodita);

        INSERT INTO CzEkokomNadoba (IdRegistrace, IdSubjektNad, IdCzEkokomNadobaTyp, IdCzEkokomNadobaKomodita, Pocet, Cetnost, Popis, Litr)
        VALUES (1, 3, @nadobaTyp, @komodita, 1, 12, NULL, 1000.000000); 
    END;
END;
```

`@nadobaTypMax` is 13 and `@komoditaMax` is 14. So I expected total 13x14 rows to be inserted. But this will insert only 13 rows (all with @nadobaTyp = 1).

There is my output:

```
nadoba typ: 1
komodita: 1

(1 row affected)
komodita: 2

(1 row affected)
komodita: 3

(1 row affected)
komodita: 4

(1 row affected)
komodita: 5

(1 row affected)
komodita: 6

(1 row affected)
komodita: 7

(1 row affected)
komodita: 8

(1 row affected)
komodita: 9

(1 row affected)
komodita: 10

(1 row affected)
komodita: 11

(1 row affected)
komodita: 12

(1 row affected)
komodita: 13

(1 row affected)
komodita: 14

(1 row affected)
nadoba typ: 2
nadoba typ: 3
nadoba typ: 4
nadoba typ: 5
nadoba typ: 6
nadoba typ: 7
nadoba typ: 8
nadoba typ: 9
nadoba typ: 10
nadoba typ: 11
nadoba typ: 12
nadoba typ: 13
```

Comment: Did you try putting some print statements in your code so you can verify the values?  That's one way to debug the issue.

Comment: @dcp I've updated the question, added print those two values.

Comment: Before the second while, you need to set komodita to 0 again

Comment: @nacho That's it! Many thanks. How can I be so blind?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)